# Anyone have the 1975 edition of "An Introduction to Microcomputers, Vol 2"?

Tags: 8-bit-microcomputers, books

I'm looking for references to the EA9002, an ill-fated design if there ever was.

Practically the only place I can find it detailed is Osborne's *Introduction to Microcomputers*, where it was chapter 11 of the original edition (1976). I cannot find this edition online, archive.org has later editions after that chapter was removed (for the 2650, har!).

Does anyone out there have a copy of the original and might be able to scan the first couple of pages of the chapter for me?

Comment: Have you tried a local library?  I found it in the catalogs of a few university libraries near me, so it does exist in libraries, and your local branch ought to be able to get a copy through interlibrary loan.

Comment: I don't get why the title asks for 1975 and the question body for 1976. (scratching head)

Answer (score 5):

Full title is **An introduction to microcomputers. Vol. 2. Some real products.**

Check this [WorldCat link](https://www.worldcat.org/title/introduction-to-microcomputers-volume-ii-some-real-products/oclc/15791692/editions?editionsView=true&lang=en). It lists a couple of entries for the 1976 edition. Follow the links on those and enter your location. The system will calculate closest libraries nearby. With Universities especially, you may also try to contact local staff there. They can probably spare a few minutes and help with a scan & email to you.

Comment: "Interlibrary Loan" is the magic phrase.